# .net create user interactive flow charts and workflow diagrams

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am trying to develop a new asp.net system (c#/ vb) that:

- Allows users to: draw workflow / flow chart diagrams (have boxes / circles connectors etc), edit / create them.
  Each part of the workflow ie box will be able to have a name, description and have files uploaded against it.
- Then once the user has created the flow along with providing all the details needed for it ie files descriptions etc i will need to be able to redraw the diagram  when they choose to view / edit it.

I have been searching and searching along with trying examples but I can't get even the basic drawing and saving to work. I have seen in [orchard CMS](http://www.orchardproject.net/) that there is a new module workflow, by Sébastien. This looks very good and I would like to try and do similar but only for the drawing / charting I don't need to be able to create a user interactive workflow, just the diagram with details against each node/ entity

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Jon

Comment: Checkout http://www.highcharts.com/ or http://d3js.org/. Should be able to store json objects and relate them to users in a .net system

Comment: Thankyou Christopher, I am also looking as jsPlumb, but can find any good examples of anyone using it to draw, save and then reopen for edit. Thanks

Comment: Anymore help advice be great. Im not having much luck working out how to achieve the above. I can't find any good examples how to use and save charts in .net. and display them etc. Really need some help thanks

Comment: jsPlumb seams like a good solution for you. Keep in mind that most of the work will be done in the browser in Javascript. You only have to use .net in the backend to save.

Comment: thanks @EduardoMolteni. I have been looking into JSplumb, trying to work out how to save from js to .net.

Comment: best way would be to use a WebAPI app and create some crud controllers or similar, then use ajax calls to these. Or look at single page applications http://www.asp.net/single-page-application